# Does a read-write-split on your galera cluster still make sense when running the servers on the same (private) cloud environment?

Tags: mariadb, clustering, galera

I know about the claims that a Galera cluster should/might perform better in a lot of cases whenever a read-write-split is set up, so there are dedicated read and write hosts in the cluster.

This makes some sense to me in case a server is hardware bound, but I was wondering if in this modern age of cloud based servers this still makes sense if they could essentially end up using the same hardware in a (private) cloud environment?

Also, in extension, what impact might high iops SSD's (which seem to be a pretty common storage medium in cloud environments already) have on the validity of this kind of setup?

Answer (score 2):

How big is the dataset?  How big is the disk?  How much RAM?  How many queries per second?  I am fishing for whether there is actually a problem you are trying to solve.

Meanwhile...

Having one "Primary" and two "read-only" "Replicas" is possible with Galera.  It may simplify establishing the connections.  Or it may make it more complex.  It may also lead to the Primary having a different load than the Replicas.

Most of today's hardware (whether in the Cloud or private) has very few parameters:

- SSD is much better than HDD, especially if I/O bound
- The cloud may be able to provide higher bandwidth, but this is unlikely to be the limiting component.
- RAM comes in many sizes.  If it is practical to have twice as much as the dataset size, then most operations will need only a little I/O.
- If the dataset is growing rapidly, the Cloud probably has a very easy way to add RAM.  Doing it yourself is a hassle.  Galera makes this "easy" by letting you take a node out of the cluster, add ram (or replace the machine) and put it back in.  If private, you are left with old hardware; if Cloud they repurpose it for someone else.

With 3 "read-write" nodes, each has similar load.  Access (read or write) needs to be redirected to some node; a "proxy" or something is useful here.

High I/O or high CPU often means "inefficient queries" -- this should be investigated *before* 'throwing hardware at the problem'.

For a very high number of read-only connections, you can hang regular Replicas off each Cluster node.  This can be scaled "infinitely".